# Same page link not working using rawurlencode() with id anchor

Tags: php, hyperlink, urlencode

EDIT: For others reading, this is resolved. %20 is not permitted in anchor IDs.

Usual reason to use an anchor id, I'm making a list of text links as titles which just link further down the page to each relevant block of text.

The code works, no errors etc, except I can't get the URL encoded successfully.
Without `rawurlencode()` the links work perfectly fine, however they have spaces which I need to manage (also wont validate).

I tried with just `urlencode()` and this works fine, but it adds + instead of %20 and I read + is to be avoided where possible (maybe that's not accurate but doesn't explain why `rawurlencode()` doesn't work).

The basic code:

```php
// The array of list titles
$aryList = array( "1. Communications", "2. Definitions and Conditions");

// Loop to output each list title as a link
foreach ($aryList as $strListValue)
  {
    echo "<a href='#".rawurlencode($strListValue)."'>$strListValue</a>";
  }

// The content with the list title as the link ID (destination)
echo "<a id='".rawurlencode($aryList[0])."'>".$aryList[0]."</a>";
echo "The text is about Communications.";
```

In the source code I can see the `rawurlencode()` replaces spaces with %20, although the URL in the browser address bar is without %20 and with spaces instead. Clicking the links does nothing.

The source code when using `rawurlencode()`:

```php
// The list title links
<a href='#1.%20Communications'>1. Communications</a>
<a href='#2.%20Definitions%20and%20Conditions'>2. Definitions and Conditions</a>

// The list IDs (destination)
<a id='1.%20Communications'>1. Communications</a>
<a id='2.%20Definitions%20and%20Conditions'>2. Definitions and Conditions</a>
```

Browser is Iceweasel 17.0.9 FWIW.

**EDIT:**
Testing from the things *durrrutti* said, it works perfectly fine when I `rawurlencode()` the anchors only, and not the IDs.

However this still leaves the issue of whitespace in the IDs.

The source code now with just anchors encoded and not IDs:

```php
// The list title links
<a href='#1.%20Communications'>1. Communications</a>
<a href='#2.%20Definitions%20and%20Conditions'>2. Definitions and Conditions</a>

// The list IDs (destination)
<a id='1. Communications'>1. Communications</a>
<a id='2. Definitions and Conditions'>2. Definitions and Conditions</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Element ID's cannot begin with anything else than alphabetic characters, ie A-Z and a-z. I think that's your problem.

**Update:** Also, the ID cannot contain percentage signs.

Comment: Hmm, I read that somewhere, but only one place on my travels/searching. The code works fine when there's no encoding at all

Comment: Right. It's weird that it still works without the URL encoding, but I just realized that you're also using `%` in your ID's. That's another character not allowed.

Comment: Thanks for that, getting somewhere. I've edited my question with more info. Summary: It works fine when only anchors are `rawurlencode()` and not on IDs, so you were right, however still leaves white space in the IDs. Any ideas for the last but of the *puzzle*?

Comment: You could just use `str_replace` for both the anchors and the ID's. Like `str_replace(" ", "", $strListValue);`.

Comment: yeah I might have to fiddle with them separately. I didn't want to as the point of the array is so one change in one place affects various places I use these. I have array keys going spare, so might utilise them. Thanks for the help. You found the main issue :)